# Installing WCF service on IIS using WIX

Tags: wcf, iis, wix, hosting

I have designed a WCF service, how do I install it to IIS on a server using WIX? Any clues where I can find step by step procedure?

Comment: I'm not familiar with WCF services, but what I would in your case it: 1) understand what the manual process of WCF service deployment include; 2) decompose this process into atomic actions, like install certain files, modify certain configs, create something in IIS, etc; 3) code these actions in terms of WiX

Answer (score 0):

Don't know how to get it WIX to install to WCF. If you know how to do it programmatically you may want to write a program that installs WCF to IIS. Then as past of your WIX install use the program.

Answer (score 0):

You an install the WCF services like a normal website using WIX.

Then later all custom actions to update the configs. Custom actions are simple call to C# or other language methods.

I am following the same steps.